# Adding block in view tabs

Tags: 8, blocks

I have tabs created using views and has contextual filter of group parent(Group ID from URL). I created a block that has a contextual filter of GID. In the block layout, I placed the block in the content region, select `Group from URL` to `Group ID:` and specify path to be shown--that is links of my tabs.

My goal is that whenever I access each tab links, the block content will be shown according to group ID from the URL.

**Given example:**

- Group-A(GID=1)
- Group-B(GID=2)
- http://localhost/tab/1/dogs
- http://localhost/tab/2/dogs

**Problem:**

My tab view with contextual filter is working but block is not showing up. How can I properly configure the block view setting to be consistent according to the GID?

**See photo below for my block settings:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your view, change the contextual filter to the following:
change:
Hide view
by
Provide default value
In Type, select the option that applies.

Comment: I already tried that but doesnt work. In the tab view I have a contextual filter of `Parent group` with `Provide default value` of `group ID from URL`. And on the block view, I have contextual filter of `Group ID` with `Provide default value` of `group ID from URL` and validation you seen on the above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The specific fix for my concern is on the block view, I have to select `Provide default value:Raw value from URL:2`.